# htaccess - redirect all URLs ending in digits

Tags: htaccess, redirects, regex

I need some help with an `.htaccess` redirect.  Here's an example.
Some of my webpages will look something like this...
`https://www.example.com/my-folder-name/my-file-name-12345678.php`.
Some pages will have 8 digits at the end like that.

I want to make it easy to get to any file who's name ends with 8 digits and `.php`.

So, in this case, I would be able to get to this file by typing
`https://www.example.com/my-folder-name/12345678`.
So, the part of the file name before the 8 digits and the `.php` extension won't need to be typed. Can that be done with `.htaccess`?

This would need to effect any file on my site ending with 8 digits.php

Answer (score 0):

> get to this file by typing `https://www.example.com/my-folder-name/12345678` So, the **part of the file name before the 8 digits** and the `.php` extension won't need to be typed.

Unfortunately, this is not possible in `.htaccess` (mod_rewrite), since there is no mechanism to essentially *search* for a file based on a partial name. You would need to *search* a directory for a file whose name *ends* with the sequence of digits passed in the URL. (Other server-side scripting languages, like PHP, can do this fairly easily - but if you have many requests/files then it's not going to be very efficient unless you employ a caching/lookup mechanism. I'm also assuming the "number" is unique and maps to a single file, otherwise this is impossible, regardless of scripting language, unless you are happy with a first-match-wins.)

In short, you would need to pass `my-file-name` in the requested URL. The `.php` extension is trivial since that is just a static string that can be hardcoded.

Alternatively, if you have access to the server config then you could potentially create a rewrite-map with all the *code* to *filename* mappings. This is essentially a lookup table that can be referenced from `.htaccess` to retrieve the corresponding *filename* given the *code* passed in the URL. Although whether this would be practical to create/maintain is another matter.